# Why is $\exp(G)$ close to 2.5?

Tags: sequences-and-series

### Background

$$
\begin{aligned}
\exp(G) &= 2.49918728\dots\\
G&= 0.91596559\dots\\
\end{aligned}
$$

G represents [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

$$
G = ∑_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}
$$

### Attemption

I tried to find a fast decaying series to represent the difference, something like:

$$
 \frac{5}{2}-\exp(G) =∑\cdots
$$

But there seems to be no series that can express $\exp(G)$

Then I considered the fast decay series after taking the logarithm

$$
\log\frac{5}{2}-G=∑\cdots
$$

The logarithm can be expanded as:

$$
\log (x+1)=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1}
$$

The question turns to proof:

$$
\log \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)-G=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2}-\frac{3 \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)^n}{2 (n+1)}\right)>0
$$

But `-3/2` is outside the convergence region.

---

Then I considered series with larger regions of convergence:

$$
\log (x)=2 \underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}\frac{1}{2 n+1}\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{2 n+1}
$$

There is also a `2n+1` here, which may represent some kind of connection.

The question turns to proof:

$$
\log \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)-G=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)^2}-\frac{2(2 n+1)}{(2 n+1)^2} \left(\frac{3}{7}\right)^{2 n+1}\right)>0
$$

This series decays exponentially and can be interpreted close to it, but it is not always positive.

### Question

Is there a series that can be used to represent differences that decays quickly and intuitive, with each term always positive?

Comment: It isn't that close to 2.5. I'd be surprised if there is any sort of deep reason for this.

Comment: They are infinity many coincidences in numerical constants. Probably $\exp(G)\simeq 2.5$ is one of them.

It is easy to find much more accurate coincidences thanks to ISC (Inverse Symbolic Calculator). For example :
$$G=0.91596559...\simeq \frac{\pi}{\ln(\pi^3-e^{-2})}\simeq 0.91596553...$$
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14161596/Mathematiques-experimentales .